# Nginx redirect forum.example.com to example.com

Tags: nginx, amazon-route53

in amazon route53 for example.com and forum.example.com I have records A with ip address to my server.

Nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  server_name example.com;   
  client_max_body_size 50M;

  # RSA
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/private.key;
  # ECDSA
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/example.com_ecc/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/example.com_ecc/private.key;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
    proxy_redirect off;
    # Socket.IO Support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 
  }

  location /ads.txt {
    root /var/www/nodebb/public/;
  }

  location /loaderio-a92c8d2496979eca3c119f44e27ee2f6.txt {
    root /var/www/nodebb/public/;
  }

}
```

How can I redirect forum.example.com to example.com ? So that url in browser will be example.com.
I tried to add

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name forum.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

but then nothing works ;) probably port blocked or smth.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see,
I saw error logs from nginx and realized that I am missing certs for this redirection